# Getting insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment while running on docker swarm with still lots of RAM available

Tags: java, docker, out-of-memory, docker-swarm

I am running docker-swarm on Ubuntu servers (VM) with 24Go of RAM.
My cluster has 2 managers and 3 nodes

Here is the memory status (on all nodes) :

```
    total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             23           5          14           0           3          17
```

A java application can't start with :

> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to
>   continue.

Any advice ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you share the VM arguments you're using?

Comment: Do you specify the amount of memory for the Java process you try to run in docker? Which Java version and which docker version do you use? Older Java versions take up to 1/4 of available memory (from the docker host) that would mean that the JVM would like to claim up to 6GB

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your answers, I am using JAVA 8, Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40, docker-compose version 1.16.1, build 6d1ac21,  the jvm is started with those arguments /bin/java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -XX:+UseG1GC -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Duser.language=fr -jar /application.jar 10 @sofo-gial

Comment: It could be that your app is quite memory demanding. Have you tried increasing your Xmx value to see if that solves the problem?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Would limits be a solution to run more stacks ?